# Discord.js bot replies/responds a message when mentioned

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot reply when it's mentioned. I'm using TypeScript for this and I am confused. I searched multiple solutions but I think its for js because it's always an error and some code doesn't exist.
Here's the code I originally tried

```
    const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
})

client.on('ready',()=>{
    console.log('bot is ready')
})
client.on('messageCreate',(message)=>{
    if(message.content === '@bot-test'){
        message.reply({
            content: 'I heard you'
        })
    }
})
```

It doesn't work with mentions but works with messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is to do with the whay you look with mentions

When you see a mention, it looks to you as `@username`, however the discord bot see's it as: `<@!userid>`

For example `@abisammy` is actually `<@!468128787884670986>`

To fix this change the if statement from

```
if (message.content === "@bot-test"){
```

to:

```
if(message.content === `<@!${client.user.id}>`){
```

This should then work

Note when using typescript you will have to add `client.user` to the if statement

**Typescript only**

```js
if(client.user && message.content === `<@!${client.user.id}>`){
```